# Твердість приголосного т у дієсловах

Tags: орфографія, діалекти

Займаюся перекладом і мені необхідно стилізувати мовлення персонажа, передавши у субтитрах його мовлення з подільським говором.

Наразі намагаюся розібратися з одним із елементів говору, а саме твердістю приголосного **т** у дієсловах 3-ї особи однини і множини теперішнього часу і 2-ї особи множини наказового способу, наприклад у словах *рóбит, нóсит, рóбл'ат, нóс'ат, роб’íт, нос’íт*.

Власне, є умовне речення "Мені так сильно болить, що я от-от розпадуся". Якщо врахувати цей елемент, то слово *болить* мало б звучати як *болит*. Але як тоді правильно записувати слова в цьому говорі? Прибирати м'який знак із закінчення чи замінювати його апострофом?

Тобто *болит* чи *болит'*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це *не дуже* реґламентовано правописом, але апостроф також можна вживати і для усѣку чи скорочѣння слів. Наприклад була [рекомендація](https://archer.chnu.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/4020/%D0%A2%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%A7%D0%A3%D0%9A%20%D0%94..pdf#page=30) до правописа-2019, котра, схоже, і не стала дійсністю:

> Окрім цього, апостроф рекомендують вживати для передавання вимови усіченого слова в розмовному й поетичному мовленні: *до’дної* «до одної», *ями*; *мо’* «може».

Чому *не дуже*, бо все таки використовують ся як скорочѣння, але лише в [певних випадках](//files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf):

> § 146. Імена та прізвища (прізвиська)
>
> Примітка 1. Скорочені компоненти прізвищ та імен пишемо з власними іменами з апострофом: *Д’Аламбе́р, д’Артанья́н, Д’Обіньє́; О’Ке́йсі, О’Ко́ннор* (але *О. Ге́нрі* — псевдонім письменника);

> § 147. Похідні прикметники
>
> Прикметники від прізвищ на зразок *Д’Аламбе́р* зберігають апостроф після частки: *д’аламбе́рівський*.

Існуїть думка, наприклад такої [дотримував ся Пономарів](//www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/10/151026_ponomariv_blog72_ko), що варто розрізняти форми стягнені від скорочених:

> **Читач Микита хоче знати, чому при скороченні слів *тре'*, *тра'* (замість *треба*), *мо'* (замість *може*) апостроф ставимо, а в слові *нема* – не ставимо.**
>
> Тому що *нема* – це не скорочена форма, а стягнена. Таке явище властиве багатьом дієсловам у третій особі однини теперішнього часу. Порівняйте: *співає – співа*, *літає – літа*, *має – ма*, *немає – нема*.

В цьому єсть певна лоґіка, бо сучасні [прикметники](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) зазвичай неповні, тобто стягенні: *синя — синяя*, *синє — синєє*, і жодних позначок для стягнѣннь не використовуїмо.

Це чимось нагадуїть ділему анґлійської мови стосовно [*ing*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8ng%E2%9F%A9) і ґ-випадѣннє, що вимовляїсть ся як *in*, але маїть способи запису як *in* та *inʼ*. І другий спосіб зазвичай використовують, коли треба прям підкреслити (*to emphasize*), що наявне ґ-випадѣннє.

Тож, якщо мова про загальний усталений звичай, то *апостроф непотрібний*, а тому достатньо просто писати відповѣдно вимовѣ, тобто ***болит***.

Answer (score 0):

### Твердість приголосного «т» у дієсловах (Подільський говір)

[image]

[**Подільський говір**](http://litopys.org.ua/ukrmova/um180.htm) сформувався під  впливом [багатьох культур](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) і набув форми великої кількості діалектів, які мають свої унікальні [фонетичні і лексичні особливості](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80).

> Твердість приголосного т у дієсловах 3-ї особи однини і множини
> теперішнього часу і 2-ї особи множини наказового способу:
> *рóбит, нóсит, рóбл'ат, нóс'ат, роб’íт, нос’íт*

У загальних назвах в сучасній українській мові апостроф вживається виключно перед голосними і не вживається наприкінці слова. Тому,

**Бóлит** з твердим **т** і наголосом на **ó**.

> **Спи́на бóлит**
>
> **Нóги бóл’ат**
>
> **Мені бóл’аче**

Comment: − < В українській мові апостроф вживається перед голосними > Відсутні докази чи џерела, пак моя відповідь на чинний правопис як џерело це спростовуїть, тобто це ще брехня. < Бóлит з твердим т і наголосом на ó > — [майже] те саме: де џерело? Історична вставка про подільский говір зайва. < бóл’ат > — до чого ця цітата під мовлѣння персонажа, коли Вікіпедія _для прикладу_ використовуїть [транскріпцію](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Транскрипція_(лінгвістика)) — загадка.

Comment: @Sútnôstj, перепрошую, та ваше посилання на примітку в чинному Правописі пояснює вжиток апострофа у власних іменах іншомовного походження і жодним чином у загальних. Тож як звинувачуєте, тим більш у брехні, то будьте ласкаві аргументувати і довести свою позицію. Якщо, на вашу думку, апостроф вживається перед приголосними, наведіть декілька прикладів таких слів.

Comment: Дивно, що мені треба пояснювати очевидне: волосні і загальні слова однаково належать і підпорядковуються українській, пак вже відомі явища, коли перші стають другими: дізель, ват, гуліґан ітд. Мовчу, що є видозмінені як: болґарка, корейка, вєтнамка ітд. Тож… це було до чого? Нагадаю вашу тезу, котру ви змінили, але суть, як вже зрозуміло з попереднього речїння, не дуже змінила ся: < В українській мові апостроф вживається перед голосними >. Но і приклади до < апостроф вживається перед приголосними > вже були наведені.

Comment: Будемо вважати, що формально я був і лишаюся правий. Та, з огляду на історію української мови та її видозмінення протягом часів, ваші зауваження є цілком доречні, а попередня відповідь ще й надає додаткової цінності цьому треду вцілому.